# Dealing with edited fields left in blank on subform

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am having a problem when an user decides to "clear/delete" a line entered on the form during the first update.

I have a form with a subform to give the user the possibility of multiple entries, however, after the user has first edited any field on the subform the respective record gets dirty and recorded, so if the user decides to not use anymore that record and deletes all the info for that line, that line which now is all blank still being recorded, and this is giving me blank lines in my data (The TransactionID and ID are not shown to the user on the form, I added it for the sake of this post).

This can also accidentally happen if on the "new" line, which is not dirty, the user hits any key by mistake, and even deleting it straight away, the record gets dirty for good, so it ends being recorded completely in blank.

I couldn't find a way to avoid recording this blank lines.

I would like to know if it is possible to have buttons to "add a new line" and "delete a line", just like, on the last line it would have a "+" to add new line (so the "new not dirty" line wouldn't appear automatically), and on the precedent lines would have a "-" to remove that specific record (this is just an idea, it can be in any kind of way).

Is that achievable? If it is not, is there a way to simply avoid blank lines to be saved? Like, saving jumping those blank lines, just like in a loop?

---

More information added for the sake of better explanation.

I didn't include the code before as there is no code behind this, this is just access natural recording set. I am not using DAO Record Set nor SQL to "save" the records (just to delete from table in a discard event), I am using normal bounded controls.

The modifications I did were on Parent form to always stay on the Current Record (Cycle) and On Load event it always goes to new record. Thus, the buttons Save and Cancel, are used to confirm or discard the new record created on the Parent form, because, as I have previously said, the subform is used to enter multiple records under the same record on the Parent Table, in other words, Relationship One-To-Many, therefore the button "Close" holds a simple code for deleting the last entry on the Parent Table (as it still on the current record) and as the tables have "Delete Cascade Relationship" all the information entered into the subform/Child Table get automatically deleted, so I just had to handle the data inserted into the Parent Table, whereas, the save button is used to get the confirmation of saving from the user, and make sure that the user will fill all the fields prior to save.

That is pretty much the code on this form, which is below.

But before the code, I would like to reinforce that, I have made use of the "BeforeUpdate" event, which works fine, it makes the user to add all the fields before opening a new record on the subform, but let's suppose that the user enters 10 records on the subform, then the user decides to "Delete" one of the records (which in this case is not the last one, so he cannot just press "ESC" and I cannot just run "Me.Undo"), so if the user clears the fields (just like in the images I have provided, as I don't know how to delete a record in this scenario yet), the before update event gets triggered and doesn't allow the user to do anything while he/she fills in the blank fields, not even to click in "Cancel". Therefore, in my "Save" button I check all the fields and if one of them is "dirty" them the user must fill all the subsequent fields, however, if all the fields are "empty", the user is still able to save.

In the beginning I thought that those "blank lines" wouldn't happen so often and I would have to clean them sporadically, but it is unbelievable, the amount of blank lines that have been created by the users. I have to clean them almost every week.

I really would like a way to create "+ add line" and "- delete line" buttons, because if the user wants to delete a line he just click on "-" button, the same for add new line.

Again, I appreciate the help. I am really struggling on this. Thanks all.

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click()

If IsNull(Me.TransactionDate) _
    And IsNull(Me.SupplierPayee) _
    And IsNull(Me.TotalReceipt) Then
    MsgBox "Form in blank!", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Saving..."
    Exit Sub
End If

If IsNull(Me.TransactionDate) _
    Or IsNull(Me.SupplierPayee) _
    Or IsNull(Me.TotalReceipt) Then
    MsgBox "Please fill in all the fields", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Transaction not Saved"
    Exit Sub
End If
    
    Me![subfrmPCHeaderDetail].SetFocus
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acFirst

If IsNull(Me.TransactionDate) _
    Or IsNull(Me.SupplierPayee) _
    Or IsNull(Me.TotalReceipt) _
    Or IsNull(Form_frmPCHeaderDetail.Item) _
    Or IsNull(Form_frmPCHeaderDetail.ItemAmount) _
    Or IsNull(Form_frmPCHeaderDetail.VATRate) _
    Or IsNull(Form_frmPCHeaderDetail.DescriptionPurpose) Then
    MsgBox "Please fill in all the fields", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Transaction not Saved"
    Exit Sub
    
ElseIf Form_frmPCHeaderDetail.ItemAmount = "0" Then
    MsgBox "Amount cannot be €0.00", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Transaction not Saved"
    Form_frmPCHeaderDetail.ItemAmount.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

If Not Me.TotalReceipt.Value = Form_frmPCHeaderDetail.GrossTotal _
    Or IsNull(Me.TotalReceipt) Then
    MsgBox "Please check the Receipt Amount Details as ""Gross Total"" and ""Receipt Total"" are not matching"
    Exit Sub
End If


If Me.ReceiptScanned.AttachmentCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Please scan the receipt and add it to this transaction", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Add the Receipt"
    Me.AddReceiptScanned.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

If Me.TransactionDate > Date Then
    MsgBox "Future Transaction Date not allowed", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Transaction not Saved"
    Me.TransactionDate.SetFocus
    Exit Sub

Else
    Dim Result As Long
    Result = MsgBox("Saving Transaction!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                "Attention!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                "You will not be able to delete nor modify any detail of this transaction!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                "Are you sure you would like to save this transaction?" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                "Click ""YES"" to save, or click ""NO"" to return.", vbExclamation + vbYesNo, "Save Transaction?")

    If Result = 6 Then
    
        DoCmd.Save
        DoCmd.Requery

        Form_frmPCHeader.TransactionDate.SetFocus
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
        MsgBox "Transaction added successfully to the Petty Cash Register", _
                vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Petty Cash transaction added"
    End If
End If 
End Sub

Private Sub btnClose_Click()

Dim LastID As Long
Dim Result As Long
    
If IsNull(TransactionID) Then
    DoCmd.Close
    Exit Sub
End If

LastID = TransactionID

MsgBox("Closing without saving!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                "If you want to discard the entries, click ""YES"", or click ""NO"" to return.", vbCritical + vbYesNo, "Discard Entries?")

If Result = 6 Then

    Application.Echo False
    Me.Painting = False
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    
    Me.TransactionDate = "31/12/2099"
    Me.SupplierPayee = "Discarded"
    Me.TotalReceipt = 0

    DoCmd.Save
    DoCmd.Requery
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM tblPCHeader WHERE TransactionID = " & LastID & ""
    DoCmd.Close
    
    Application.Echo True
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    
End If

End Sub
Private Sub Form_Load()
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
End Sub
```

[image: Before user's deleting all fields contents]

[image: After user's deleting all fields contents]

Comment: Obviously, the line creation is triggered by the code, which you don't let us look at. However, you say that the entry is created, you say, based on the form being dirty. That appears to be too sensitive a trigger. Give your forms an <KBD>OK</KBD> button and make sure nothing gets recorded until the user presses that button.

Comment: Yes, can have + and - buttons on each row. Perhaps use form BeforeUpdate event to validate record. If user uses Esc to undo entries, a record should not be created. If you have code populating field that's another issue.

Comment: Hi @Variatus, I have edited my post to add the codes and more information and case illustration. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @June7, I have also explained that I had made use of the "Before Update" event and I added a scenario case. I am really happy to know that it is possible to add the "add line" and "delete line" buttons, please just give me the North (way). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a Delete (-) button, consider code:

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

For Add (+) button, just move to new record row with code you already know.
`Docmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec`